# Why docker container out of memory without "cpuset-cpus" parameter?

Tags: docker, containers, out-of-memory

I create two containers (which provide restful API) via following docker commands.
The only one difference is "--cpuset-cpus="0" for setting specific core number.
However I found that container A will be crashed, if I submit over 150 http requests.
Then, I check the memory via "docker stats container A",
memory usage gradually increases with receiving the number of http requests,
finally container crashed.
But if I set "cpuset-cpus" argument into Container B, memory stability is not affected by http requests,
the container B will not be crashed.

Does anybody know why container will be crash without setting cpuset-cpus?

btw, my server has 32 cores cpu and 512gb.

Container A:

```
docker run \
-d \
-e PYTHONPATH=/app/custom_component:$PYTHONPATH \
-v /home/hibot_agents/proj.1845.cache:/app:rw \
--name test_1845 \
--memory="512M" \
--memory-swap="1g" \
--cpus="0.25" \
--network="chatbot-network" \
images/chatbot-server:2.0.0-full \
  rasa run --enable-api --endpoints endpoints.yml -vv
```

Container B:

```
docker run \
-d \
-e PYTHONPATH=/app/custom_component:$PYTHONPATH \
-v /home/hibot_agents/proj.1845.cache:/app:rw \
--name test_1845 \
--memory="512M" \
--memory-swap="1g" \
--cpus="0.25" \
--cpuset-cpus="0" \
--network="chatbot-network" \
images/chatbot-server:2.0.0-full \
  rasa run --enable-api --endpoints endpoints.yml -vv
```

Comment: Is this related to Kubernetes?

Comment: If your application has a memory leak, that would be an application issue. See [mcve].

Comment: @coderanger the above code is not related to Kubernates, however my production environment is k8s and faces the same issue. Sorry I modify  the tags.